# Facebook Ionic Permissions (birthday)

Tags: android, ios, facebook, ionic-framework

I am building an ionic app that needs to use more than the basic facebook profile information. I understand Facebook has a process for this in which they ask you to give login information to test how your ionic app may use it. If the app is not yet published and not outside of development - how is this accomplished?

Comment: It’s not ... you are of course supposed to finish your development first, before you submit for review.

Comment: That is unfortunate, what about the case when this integration is required for you to be able to release the app?

Comment: Are you actually creating native builds for both of those platforms? If so, you’re supposed to upload a simulator build for review. If that is not possible, you upload a dummy file instead and tell them in your review instructions where else they can get the app (download it from some link you provide) ... and if even that is not possible, explain the situation, and provide a screencast that explains everything your app does.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You already have package name(s) to define in the Facebook Developer for android and ios apps.
It's perfectly possible to test while in development as long as you register your iOS and/or Android apps in Facebook Developer.
If you want to use the native Facebook login you can test and debug with

```
$ ionic cordova emulate
```

Comment: I was more referencing Facebook's ability to test the app since they would need to approve the Login for additional permissions. If your app isn't public I don't know how they'd access it

Comment: It is possible to submit a screencast together with detailed information on how users will use the app and the data provided by Facebook.

See this link :

[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit)